# Rest API order by for Rootfolder won't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I try to order a Rest API query (SharePoint Online) via CSOM. Unfortunately it won't work. I want to get the files & folders of the rootfolder of a library sorted by name.

```
        url: baseUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + projectLibraryName + "')/Rootfolder?$expand=Folders,Files,Files/ModifiedBy" +
            "&$select=Files/ModifiedBy/Title,Files/ModifiedBy/Email,Files/Name,Files/TimeLastModified,Files/ServerRelativeUrl,Folders/Name,Folders/TimeLastModified,Folders/ServerRelativeUrl"+
            "&$orderby=Folders/Name,Files/Name",
```

Can somebody see why?

Comment: Are you getting any error message ??

Comment: No error message, I just get an unsorted result

Comment: Try it with orderby=FileLeafRef and check ?

Comment: orderby=FileLeafRef, same behaviour result is unsorted

Comment: Can you check with `/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('"+ projectLibraryName +"')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Editor/Name,Editor/EMail,EncodedAbsUrl,Modified&$expand=Editor,File,Folder&$orderby=FileLeafRef`? I think it might solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still the results are unsorted. Even if I try /Items?$select=FileLeafRef&$top=1000&$order‌​by=FileLeafRef

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirement to get all folders' names under root folder of  "Help Documents" library, sorted by Name(default column). Below is the rest call I have used and it is working for me.

```
   function GetLinks() {
    var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    var folderUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl +"/Help Documents";
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+ folderUrl +"')/Folders?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Name&$orderby=Name",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        alert(data.d.results[0].Name);
        alert(data.d.results[1].Name);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Rest below, order by Created Time:

```
_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Jerrydoc')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Created&$top=10&$order‌​by=Created desc
```

[image]